# How to disable separate Fody plugin in Release mode?

Tags: c#, .net, fody

I'm using MethodDecorator.Fody (for injecting debug stuff) and some other plugins (PropertyChaged etc.).

Is there any way to disable MethodDecorator.Fody in Release build mode but keep the others enabled?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/Fody/Home/blob/master/pages/configuration.md#merging-configurations

Comment: Yes, it seems))